# How should I find element in Selenium WebDriver in Java if there are blank spaces in name and id?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I have problem with one of the selects on page that I want to locate.

```
SELECT name="" id="" onblur=""

OPTION selected></OPTION

OPTION value=324686977>324686977</OPTION

OPTION value=324689385>324689385</OPTION

/SELECT
```

The parent name is "`ATTR_SECVOIPNETA`" and it generates few more `Selects` with blank spaces too.
I tried few options before asking, however I have no more ideas.

I attached a screen to be more specific how problem looks like.

[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hF8A.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per screenshot, this is a part of table and if you can locate label `"Numer wirtualny"` (in this case), you can also locate the corresponding `"select" field(drop down).`

Here is a sample `xpath` for your use-

```
//*[@id='ATTR_SECVOIPNETA']//descendant::*[contains(text(),'Numer wirtualny')]//following-sibling::select
```

or

```
//*[@id='ATTR_SECVOIPNETA']//child::*[contains(text(),'Numer wirtualny')]//following-sibling::select
```

Note:

1. Make sure you talk to your developer to add some ids. :)
2. `Descendant` is similar to grand grand child. In this case you can use `"child".`

Comment: Unfortunetely they are not working, I've checked with multiple variations, with slashes, without slashes, even tried to change xpath to cssSelector, its not working :<